How to detect the addition of overlay mounts on a running system?
Problem:
Using File Integrity Monitoring (FIM) software, I want to detect when files are added/deleted/modified.
However, the current solution is based on iNotify.
It seems that if an attacker were to add an overlay mount and then add nefarious executables over the real ones that would fail to be detected by the iNotify mechanism.
Is there a way of doing this? An attacker could quite easily add an overlay, paste over the top of the anti-virus/FIM/root kit hunter executable without being detected.
iNotify doesn't seem to work, and this is apparently a known issue
